# Unable to unzip tar.gz in ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, tar

I want to unzip *tar.gz* in terminal. I don't want to use any application from *ubuntu sofware center*.

Answer (score 1):

Run the below commands on terminal to extract tar.gz file,

```
cd /path/to/the/directory/which/contains/filename.tar.gz
tar -xzvf filename.tar.gz
```